# Как на c# (или на др. языке) отлавливать комбинацию клавиш и работать с файлом?

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день.

Хочу сделать следующее:   
Выделяю слово  в браузере/ворде... (например, на английском/немецком) и жму определённую комбинацию клавиш, например: ctrl+1 - выделенный фрагмент должен записаться в значение[слово]

Потом выделяю другое слово и жму ctrl+2 - выделенный фрагмент должен записаться в значение[перевод]

Это хочется делать быстро, чтоб выделил слово и нажал комб клав, затем перевод и в итоге занести в текстовый файл что-то типа

```
cat -tab- кошка
dog -tab- собака
....
```

Ну как-то так. Как использовать windows api, т.к. приложение лучше чтоб было в трее, но отслеживало данную комбинацию клавиш.

Как такое или подобное реализовать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Подобная тема уже обсуждалась[на этом сайте][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/130391/winforms-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По быстрому написал тут на Builde're подобие твоей программы!

Алгоритм такой: выделяешь "слово", жмешь Ctrl+C, затем Ctrl+1, "слово" попадает в поле слово, далее выделяешь "перевод", жмешь Ctrl+C, затем Ctrl+2, "перевод" попадает в поле перевод и автоматически добавляется в текстовое поле ниже, между "словом" и "переводом" ставится табуляция и происходит автосохранение в файл "translate.txt" в той же папке, где exe'шник программы.

[Вот прога v1.1 & исходник](http://rghost.ru/8MPfFy8Fq)
Изменения:

1. [+] Легкое Изменение интерфейса.
2. [+] Добавлено сворачивание в трей.
3. [+] Не нужно нажимать Ctrl+C срабатывает при Ctrl+1 > слово и Ctrl+2 > перевод.
4. [+] При автосохранение воспроизводит звук Beep(), удобно когда прога в треи.

[image]

Comment: Огромное спасибо. А возможен ещё вариант, что б нажать Ctrl+1, и прога определила активное окно, и если там выделен текст, то скопировать его в буфер?ну это так- думаю- ещё для ещё более быстрой работы. Спасибо за прогу

Comment: > Роман - программа обновлена!

Comment: Супер - огромное спасибо. Как раз то что надо. Нигде такого не находил. Очень удобно для добавления в Anki для обучения и интервальных повторений. Буду теперь осваивать C++ - давно уже собирался.

Comment: wh1te, подскажите ещё. Работаю ещё с немецким языком и там есть буквы ä,ü,ö и они не отображаются. Как изменить кодировку и сделать, что б это работало? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

На вскидку сказать точно не могу, но с выделенным текстом работает объект Clipboard (c#).
Нажатия клавиш ловятся событиями, например, `Key_Pressed`, где в параметрам уже указаны, какие клавиши были нажаты, и далее, используя объект Keys, можно их сравнивать и т.д. Чтобы приложение отправить в трей, можно использовать компонент (примерное название) notifyIcon (пример: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread434709.html). Надеюсь, что помог. С уважением.